# с# json.net десериализация и использование данных

Tags: c#, json, json.net

мне необходимо получать доступ к любому полю в этом json:

```
 {
  "server_time": 1511698306,
  "pairs": {
    "ltc_btc": {
      "decimal_places": 8,
      "min_price": 0.00000001,
      "max_price": 10000,
      "min_amount": 0.0001,
      "min_total": 0.0001,
      "hidden": 0,
      "fee": 0.2,
      "fee_buyer": 0.2,
      "fee_seller": 0.2
    },
    "nmc_btc": {
      "decimal_places": 8,
      "min_price": 0.00000001,
      "max_price": 10000,
      "min_amount": 0.0001,
      "min_total": 0.0001,
      "hidden": 0,
      "fee": 0.2,
      "fee_buyer": 0.2,
      "fee_seller": 0.2
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

я должен получать данные из server_time, но и список всех пар в объекте pairs (например ltc_btc, nmc_btc).

мой код выглядит так:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonPairs);
foreach (JToken tkn in o["pairs"])
{
result += tkn.ToString();
}
```

но так я получаю информацию по каждой паре как текст. я не знаю как мне теперь и это распарсить.

Comment: я не могу генерировать классы так как моих пак вроде ltc_btc сотни и они могу добавляться.

Comment: Мне вот интересно как вопрос 18 года мог быть задан раньше чем мой заданный в 17 году. Вопрос к Андрею NOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В отладке прекрасно видно, как именно это парсить. Не особо задумываясь над смыслом, накидал вот такое за пару минут:

```
  var test = JToken.Parse(json);
  var pairs = test["pairs"];
  foreach (JProperty pair in pairs)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Name);
    var btc = pair.Value;
    var minTotal = btc["min_total"];
  }
```

Если не хочется парсить поля так, можно добавить класс:

```
  public class Btc
  {
    public int decimal_places { get; set; }
    public double min_price { get; set; }
    public int max_price { get; set; }
    public double min_amount { get; set; }
    public double min_total { get; set; }
    public int hidden { get; set; }
    public double fee { get; set; }
    public double fee_buyer { get; set; }
    public double fee_seller { get; set; }
  }
```

И тогда его надо будет десериализовывать:

```
  var test = JToken.Parse(json);
  var pairs = test["pairs"];
  foreach (JProperty pair in pairs)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Name);
    var btc = pair.Value.ToObject<Btc>();
    Console.WriteLine(btc.min_total);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас немного неверно задан вопрос. А точнее, вы не указали, что значения у вас динамичны и могут меняться и добавляться!

Для подобных случаев отлично подходит `Dictionary<>`.

Создадим под ваш JSON пару классов, основной и объекта `pairs`:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("server_time")]
    public long ServerTime { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Pair> Pairs { get; set; }
}

public class Pair
{
    [JsonProperty("decimal_places")]
    public long DecimalPlaces { get; set; }
}
```

В `Root` классе, мы указываем объект `server_time` и словарь `Pairs`, у которого ключом будет `string` значение, а значением над класс `Pair`. В классе `Pair` указываем все объекты, которые есть в `JSON` (я лично поленился это сделать и для примера указал одно). Обратите внимание, что указал `JsonProperty`, это некая пометка, которая говорит десериализатору, что данное значение в оригинале называется по другому. Это позволит нам переименовывать переменные как мы захотим!

Отлично, классы есть, осталось дело за малым, десериализация:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);

foreach (var pair in json.Pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value.DecimalPlaces);
}
```

В данном коде мы десериализируем наш `JSON` из `string` значения в наш `Root` класс. Далее для примера я прошелся по всем значениям `Pairs` и вывел на консоль их ключ, а также значение переменной `DecimalPlaces`.

Ответом будет:

```
ltc_btc
8
nmc_btc
8
```

В итоге, мы получили все необходимые данные с изменяющимися значениями в `pairs`!
P.S. Я лично работаю с библиотекой `Newtonsoft.Json`, чего и вам советую!

Comment: я рассматривал эту библиотеку с самого начала, но из-за недостатка опыта не осилил, пока ждал ответа подумал также смотреть в сторону Dictionary<>

Comment: @АртурШмаков Ну, как по мне - Newtonsoft.Json, менее запутанная и в разы облегчает работу с json файлами. Что касается примера - все это с легкостью можно переписать на стандартные методы, главное уловить суть и за основу взять словарь, который в ключе будет содержать имя, а в значение все необходимые данные.